# Angular ngIf unexpected behavior

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, chromium

I have simple HTML form named `myForm`. One of the form fields has `ng-if="true"`on it.

`console.log(myForm)` shows that the form is an array containing 5 items. 
`console.log(myForm.length)` returns the number 4.

**Please see the example**
http://plnkr.co/edit/MHi6FpEs9l0wbC96Cx6b?p=preview

Comment: Plnkr is down. Can you post somewhere else?

Comment: I get "Import error - Plunk not found" now.

Comment: It works fine for me and for Tim below. Is it still down for you?

Comment: I still get `Import error - Plunk not found`. This is in latest Chrome, Safari, et al. I kind of hate that everyone uses Plnkr, because I haven't clicked a working plnkr link in a very long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hung me up recently as well, and after looking into it a little I believe the issue is that ng-if sets a [$watch in its link function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L88), so even though your directive's link function may execute after ng-if, the `$watch` won't be triggered until the next `$digest` (or later in the same one? Not entirely sure).

So both directives are compiled, then linked, and finally `$watch` is triggered and the ng-if DOM element is inserted.

If you wrap your code in a `$timeout` it will reflect the proper value, as the `$digest` will have completed:

http://plnkr.co/edit/T8dXfRhsgFWGg0I232Vo?p=preview

The reason that the console shows the length of the form as 4 is because when your directive link function runs, ng-if has been compiled which removes your input from the DOM and [replaces it with a comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/compile.js#L1230) that looks like `<!-- ngIf: true -->`, but the `$watch` declared in the ng-if link function has not run yet.

ng-if is waiting on the `$watch` to then add a clone of your input back to the DOM ***if*** the `$watch` expression is truthy, but since it hasn't run at the time of your link function and a comment is not a valid form input, the form length is 4.

Order of events if I understand it correctly:

1. ng-if compilation (remove the input and replace it with a comment, form length 4)
2. your directive compilation
3. ng-if linking
4. your directive linking (still no input, form length is still 4) <- here is where you are setting scope.formLength
5. ng-if $watch (input clone added if expression is true, form length 5)

Form.length returns 4 despite there still being 5 elements because as per the spec, [form.length returns the length of the elements array](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/forms.html#dom-form-elements), which includes [button, fieldset, input, keygen, object, output, select, and textarea](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/forms.html#category-listed) but not div :)

The reason console.log shows a length of 4, but 5 valid inputs is because you are passing in a reference to the form element.  At least in Chrome, an instant snapshot of the object passed in to console.log is displayed in italics, but when you click to expand the object in the console the current object that is referenced is shown, which is why the form is shown to have 5 valid inputs.  Unfortunately [the snapshot in italics is condensed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316#c38), so you can't see from the console.log that the form only has 4 inputs.

If you clone the input at the time of the console.log you can see that it actually doesn't have the 5th input.

```
var myFormClone = myForm.cloneNode(true);
console.log(myForm) //has 5 inputs by the time you see it
console.log(myFormClone) //has 4 inputs
```

Relevant chromium issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why the output on the console shows there are 5 items in the array but array.length returns 4? They are in the same cycle but return different values. Open your console on the plunker to see what I mean.

Comment: Updated my answer and the plunkr :)

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I don't think that is the issue. I updated the plunker. Notice how I am now calling `console.log()` two times.  The first call logs the form element that has 5 elements in it, the second call is for the length of the form element object and it evaluates to 4. As far as I understand these to calls are in the same digest cycle so there should not be conflicting form lengths.

Comment: I think you need to freeze the plunkr, because I don't see any console.logs.  Also, the form DOES have 5 elements, but the fourth element is simply a `<div class="form-group">` with the ng-if comment inside, which is not a valid input and is why form.length is 4. Element !== input, the form length is reflecting the number of inputs, not the number of elements in the form.

Comment: I understand your confusion though, here's an example of what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/M4mXUdVNDfaFpEVgFTsk?p=preview

Comment: So apparently length also counts a bunch of other elements (not just inputs, but still not divs) in forms, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ha ha this comment thread is getting out of hand! I froze the plnkr. The form has 5 elements that _per the spec_ should be counted as 5 elements. See the console now on the original plnker. The fourth element is **not** a `<div>` per the console log.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean! You're passing in a reference to an element to console.log, which by the time you see it WILL contain a valid 5th input.  You can see that it actually does not contain the 5th input if you clone the form at the time of the console.log or just simply set a breakpoint on the console.log and inspect the form :) http://plnkr.co/edit/FfnlmPP5jq0eZPgq8Tpk?p=preview